# Create new page in the database automatically according to the number of paragraphs

Tags: pagination, blogs

I am creating a post, but it contains many paragraphs, and I wish that every post had no more than 5 paragraphs. That is, if my post has 15 paragraphs will automatically be divided into three posts.

Ex: I created the post titled "My first post" and he has 15 paragraphs. When sending to the database it will be divided into three posts of paragraphs 5, with different urls (site.com/my-first-post/page-1 - site.com/my-first-post/page-2 - site.com/my-first-post/page-3) and with the same title or plus any parameters (My first post - part 1 / My first post - part 2, ...)

Any help will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The concept you are looking for is 'pagination'.

Can't give you any code as you haven't specified a language. Here's an example written in PHP (it's actually from the CodeIgniter framework) http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/160280/

Essentially, you split the article into an array. The break element is the EOL character (be carefully to handle \r and \n). Then you splice the array to take the relevant 5 elements of the array, based on the page id.

Comment: Hello, Blowski
thank you for your help. I am new to stackoverflow and I will not be posted the question in the proper location. perhaps should have done in wordpress.stackexchange.com. Correct me if I'm wrong.

I'm trying to implement this functionality in Wordpress project. Maybe there is a plugin that does it. Any other ideas?

(note: response to GoogleTranslate translated in Portuguese)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) You will probably get a better and quicker answer on wordpress.stackexchange.com, but it's ok on this site as well. Maybe this plugin will help - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-paginate/

Comment: Ok, I'll test the plugin and try to adapt to my need, soon I'll post the result here. Thank you.